# write month name to span in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

Trying to write month name within a span tag to act as the title to a calendar, but everything I try I can't get it to work. I don't want to write it inside the HTML document since I have a lot of JS to write and it would just unnecessarily clutter the HTML document, which would make it hard to fix at a later date if you need to. I'm only including the necessary code

JS filename: JMCalendar.js (it's relevant)

HTML Code:

```
<head>
<script src="JMCalendar.js" ref="text/javascript></script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="mName" onload="curMonth()"></span>
</body>
```

Javascript Code

```
var nD = new Date();
var months = ["Janurary", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var mNm = document.getElementById("mName");
var curMonth = function()
   {
      return mNm.innerHTML = months[nD.getMonth], true;
   };
```

What am I doing wrong? I tested the JS in JSHint, didn't show anything wrong. Also in this instance what's the best event to use "onLoad", or what? should "mNm.innerHTML" within "curMonth()" be on its own line? Do I have to return a condition?

Again want to work in the confines of the table I made, I'd rather not have to force the calendar style into a plugin and don't really have the time to mess with third party plugins and potential licensing issues. Please keep answers to the problem stated, JQuery alternatives are fine if that's a better one to use than trying to get it to run in JS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need

*edit, I think I see now what you're trying to do, if you're trying to check if your current month is correct, you can use:

```
return mNm.innerHTML === months[nD.getMonth()] ? true : false;
```

Otherwise you could just use

```
mNm.innerHTML = months[nD.getMonth()]
```

Instead of

```
return mNm.innerHTML = months[nD.getMonth], true;
```

Comment: When I was messing with another javascript file for another part of the site, the functions wouldn't run unless I defined the functions. someone told me that was the problem, and when I tested it, he seemed to be right about that. I think he said that you don't have to declare a function within the document since it assumes that you mean affect that document. Or that's at least how he explained it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `var` is messing you up. `var` usually is local, so if you did

```
function curMonth(){
    return mNm.innerHTML = months[nD.getMonth()], true;
}
```

it should work because then it will be global and able to be called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in the code. The one that causes it to fail silently is that the `curMonth` function never gets executed, since the `onload` attribute has no effect. This is a long story, but the bottom line is that there is no `load` event for a `span` element. If you fix this and run the function in another way, you will see an error message in the console log, since `mName` is undefined, The reason is that it is set before the `span` element has been parsed.

Removing unnecessary functions and variables, the job can do as follows (note that the entire JavaScript code is executed only after the entire document has loaded, so that the element has been parsed):

```html
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  document.getElementById("mName").innerHTML =
    months[new Date().getMonth()];
}
</script>
<span id="mName"></span>
```

Comment: That's interesting, I guess I need to look more into scopes since that is pretty clean and elegant. Ignoring the minor fact that I didn't want it in the HTML document, but the standalone JS document, would that still work if I moved it over to the document or do I have to then call upon it somehow (I don't know that part) either in the body or span tag?

Comment: Yes, you can put that JavaScript code and just refer to it in `<script src=...></script>`, at any point. It’s designed so that it can be placed anywhere. No call is needed, since this sets an `onload` event handler, which will run as soon as the document has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML Code:

```
<span id="mName" ></span>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function curMonth(id) {
   var nD = new Date();
   var months = ["Janurary", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
   var month = months[nD.getMonth()];
   id.innerHTML = month;
}
var mName=document.getElementById("mName");
mName.onload = curMonth(mName);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Also thanks guys for the quick responses.

Comment: Why can't I use global scope variables in my function. I had those variables in your example, outside of the function and was  trying to just use the variable names in the function. But that doesn't seem to work. I tried your code exactly and it still didn't produce anything. In my HTML I have some actual lines of javascript code tied to an "onClick" event, could that be interfering with the JS file and trying to call functions from it? The JS code is tied to an input button and it toggles between views (month and week views), It hides the current button and changes its text string value.